# Under what conditions the kernel and image of a linear bundle map are subbundles?

Tags: differential-geometry

Under what conditions the kernel and image of a linear bundle map are subbundles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're subbundles if and only if the bundle map has constant rank. See Theorem 10.34 in my *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds* (2nd edition).

Comment: @ Jack Lee,Thank you.